# Where should I go to ramp up to complex .NET 3.5 and WPF applications coming from a .NET 2.0/WinForms background?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I come from a C#/.NET 2.0 and WinForms background, but I'd really like to find a great WPF resource or tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I started out using WinForms, and then moved to silverlight, which is a subset of WPF.

The difference (IMO) between WinForms and WPF, is that WPF is more similar to the original JAVA GUI structures, where everything is based on layouts where all your items sit inside different layouts (Grids, StackPanels, WrapPanels, etc.).  WPF is also event driven, so you get the same feel as with WinForms where you have different events linked to the UIElements.

This is just a brief discussion on it, but IMO the most difficult part is to learn how to use the layouts and how to develop the GUI using XAML (The backend code for WPF and Silverlight). If you want the WYSIWYG interface, you can use Expression Blend.

Here are two tutorials I found on a search that seems to explain the basics quite well:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/BeginWPF1.aspx

and 
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/WPFTutorial.aspx